# Fetching an Image path in a plist

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, plist, mkannotation

I am trying to fetch an image path (eg. annotation1.jpg ) stored in a plist to put in a custom callout, depending on which POI it is.
Right now, I am fetching only one static image.

How can I implement that in my code?

```
   - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
        if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation) {
            CalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView = (CalloutMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"];
            if (!calloutMapAnnotationView) {
                calloutMapAnnotationView = [[[CalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                                 reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"] autorelease];
                calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 78.0f;
                UIImage *asynchronyLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"something.png"];
                UIImageView *asynchronyLogoView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:asynchronyLogo] autorelease];
                asynchronyLogoView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 2, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.width, asynchronyLogoView.frame.size.height);
                [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:asynchronyLogoView];
            }
            calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;
            calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = self.mapView;
            return calloutMapAnnotationView;
        } else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyHomeAnnotation class]]) {
            MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
            return annotationView;
        }else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MyMapAnnotation class]]) {
            MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                                   reuseIdentifier:@"NormalAnnotation"] autorelease];
            annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
            annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
            return annotationView;
        }


        return nil;
    }
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load a PLIST into an NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:pathAndFileName];
```

Once you have the dictionary, you can pull out the key you need with:

```
NSString *imageFileName = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"imageFileName"];
```

You can then create the image just as you have (as long as it is in the bundle) with:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageFileName];
```

Comment: right now, my code looks like that
`if (!calloutMapAnnotationView) {
                calloutMapAnnotationView = [[[CalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation 
                                                                                 reuseIdentifier:@"CalloutAnnotation"] autorelease];
                calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 78.0f;
NSDictionary *poiImage = [poiArray objectAtIndex:nextPoiIndex++];
   NSString *imageFileName = [poiImage objectForKey:@"imageFileName"];
   UIImage *asynchronyLogo = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageFileName"];
 asynchronyLo`

Comment: but Xcode tells me that imageFileName is not a used variable even if i incorporated correctly in my NSDictionary

Comment: I think you will need to run this through the debugger and see wether you get to the NSDictionary line, and if you do wether it creates non nil object pointer.  Likewise if the imageFileName is nil at the next line then this means that the key does not exist in your PLIST.  This could be a typo in the key name (they are case sensitive) or that the poiArray was not created properly in the first place.  Hope this helps.